# How to return list of dictionaries in the string representation format defined in Django Model?

Tags: python, django

I have a queryset, which returns the data I want after the application of a filter.
This queryset gives me the data only given in `__str__()` method of the model.
(However the type of the structure is `<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>` which I do not want.)

Currently, I can only return a queryset,

**If I try using a serializer, it returns all kinds of metadata which I did not include in `__str__()` method of my class.**

**`.values()` creates dictionaries that also includes metadata like "id" which I did not include in **str**() method of my class.**

I need a way to transform my QuerySet into a list of dictionaries (dictionaries which include model data given in `__str__()` method of the model class)

Here is an example queryset result. "SomeRecord" is the name of my model.

```
<QuerySet [<SomeRecord: latitude: 12.11, longitude:  23.23, datetime: 2020-11-14 11:00:43>]>
```

I can get this by creating a dictionary myself after the result of the queryset in the following way,

```
    dict = {}
    output = []
    queryResult = someQuerySetFilter()
    for queryset in queryResult:
        data['latitude'] = queryset.latitude
        data['longitude'] = queryset.longitude
        data['datetime'] = queryset.datetime.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
        output.append(dict)
    return output
```

I want to do it in a more Django, and maybe more efficient way.

Comment: So exactly what do you want? A list of strings? If you are only interested in the `str` of the model, I don't see why you need a dictionary in the first place.

Comment: A list of dictionaries. Dictionaries are the data given in __str__() method of my models.
The queryset works perfectly(correctly outputs only the  __str__() data)

Comment: but a `__str__` method does not return a dictionary, but a string.

Comment: Yes but I can successfully get the Queryset I want. I just want it structured in the same way as (give the same data/attributes) as in my __str__ methods. 

The attributes, not the exact same string. I dont think the problem is in that part. I also added an example of the queryset output

Comment: you'll have to create a method that does it (the same way you created a `__str__(..)` method that converted to a string representation).